# Нахождение дат, которые имеют пересечение друг с другом

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

В таблице есть один столбец с датами. Я хочу написать такой запрос, который выведет, скажем, те даты, которые отличаются друг от друга в промежутке одного часа.

```
date
-----------------
2021-05-17 15:00:00
2021-05-17 16:00:00
2021-05-17 16:30:00
2021-05-17 19:00:00
```

Необходимый результат

```
date
-----------------
2021-05-17 15:00:00
2021-05-17 16:00:00
2021-05-17 16:30:00
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для каждой записи тупо проверяем, что в диапазоне плюс-минус час есть ещё хотя бы одна запись.

```
SELECT date
FROM table t1
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM table t2
               WHERE t2.date BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, -1, t1.date)
                                 AND DATEADD(HOUR,  1, t1.date)
                AND t2.date != t1.date )
```

PS. Не работает, если есть две записи с в точности совпадающим значением даты-времени. В этом случае следует использовать сравнение уникальных выражений (например, первичного ключа) вместо `t2.date != t1.date`.

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]